# Get the application standard resource manager

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, resources

How can a dll get the ResourceManager of the application, i.e. the entry assembly, through reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, where rmc is the fully qualified resource name, If you use the default way (Properties of project and then new resource) to create a resource file it will be [YourProjectName].Properties.Resources.

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("rmc",Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

You can also use the path of the resource to get to the resource manager, have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.createfilebasedresourcemanager.aspx)